# Representation of decimal numbers with mysql float type?

Tags: mysql, database, floating-point, decimal, average

I know that it is a bad idea to store decimal values as float in mysql.

Example: If I store a product the price of $ 5.01, there is no exact floating type representation of that number.

If I you do that:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `test` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `test` (`test`) VALUES
(5.01);
```

and then you run the query

```
SELECT AVG( test ) 
FROM test
```

against that table you will end up with this:

```
mysql> select avg(test) from test;
+------------------+
| avg(test)        |
+------------------+
| 5.01000022888184 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

however if you select just the field like this:

```
mysql> select * from test;
+------+
| test |
+------+
| 5.01 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

you end up with the correct amount.

My question is: How can that be?

If float type cannot represent my value accurately?

Shouldnt the select return 5.01000022888184 as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why the plain select returns 5.01 is that it is the shortest number that is closer to the actual value than to any other floating-point number; MySQL displays this instead of converting the actual value back to the closest decimal fraction because in most cases users will perceive this result as "more correct".

The reason why `avg()` behaves differently is probably that it does its calculation using `double`, and 5.01 is of course *not* closer to the rounded-to-`float` actual value than all `double` values, because there are far more of those.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is as simple as the db stores the number as is however once you manipulate it, it is then used in the IEEE 754 form

see a previous (oracle related) question  [Oracle Floats vs Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332492/oracle-floats-vs-number)

Answer (score 0):

The real problem is that you can't do:

```
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `test` = 5.01
```

The value of a float stored in MySQL is *unknowable*

It's a huge bug, but they're not willing to fix it.  Decimal and Double have similar problems.  The only fix is to specify an exact precision for the field in your schema

```
ALTER TABLE `test` change `test` `test` FLOAT(10,2)
```

But then you loose any precision in calculating where the precision would be less specified (eg. any fractions)