# oracle value 0.1 become .1 cannot use in java playframework models

Tags: oracle, playframework, oracle11g, playframework-2.1

I try to save value 0.1 to database, but it became .1. and when i try to use it for java double type it became error. Do i need to use format method in java to be able to use it?

Comment: It didn't become `.1`, it's stored as a number (hopefully) and when you query it it's being displayed without the leading zero by default. Java shouldn't care as long as you're retreiving it as a number. Please add the relevant code and the error you're getting to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for sounding like a nagging teacher but you really need to learn some basics of computing: when stored as a number (either a float or a variable-length decimal) there is no difference between 0.1 and .1 - it's just the matter of the display format, not the underlying value. E.g. go and read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point to see how floats are typically encoded as. Also, see [Oracle Floats vs Number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332492/oracle-floats-vs-number) to understand how Oracle FLOATs are actually NUMERIC, not IEEE floats.

Secondly, always post as much source code as possible - with no information there's no way anyone can even make an educated guess of the problem.