# data type related questions in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle11g

What is the difference between oracle number data type and oracle floating data type? 
I want to create columns for salary and rate, what data type should be more comfortable for those columns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332492/oracle-floats-vs-number/332503#332503

Answer (score 0):

Anything to do with money should probably be stored as a NUMBER type, as it is not prone to IEEE-type rounding errors. All arithmetic in a NUMBER type is essentially integer, so 1.5 * 1.5 will equal 2.25, not 2.249999999......