# Can I overwrite the type mapping in QueryDSL for all DB columns?

Tags: java, querydsl

I have a legacy Oracle Database with lots of FLOAT typed columns which are actually NUMBER columns (Oracle doesn't make any difference internally, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/332520/602762 for details).

If those columns contains numbers which do not fit into Java's float I am losing precision during the internal conversion/mapping from database to Java type in QueryDSL.

Therefore I'd like to map all columns of type FLOAT in Oracle to Double in Java.

Is that possible without specifying all columns concerned separately (there are thousands of columns)?